# Controllers returning default login html page after adding Spring Oauth2 Client dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm new to spring security. I have a custom oauth 2.0 provider. I was trying to create an end point "/test"(doesn't use oauth 2.0) which will hit another end point x(x uses oauth 2.0). Here is the code that I wrote to get started -

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class OAuthController {
    
    @GetMapping(value="/test")
    public String testing() {
        System.out.println("running controller");         
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/test2", String.class);

        //this will be eventually replaced with calling end point x with oauth 2.0
    }

   @GetMapping(value="/test2")
    public String testing2() {
        return "Hello from test2";
    }
}
```

pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

application.yml :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myclient:
            client-id: XXX
            client-secret: XXX
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: default
            provider: myauthProvider
        provider:
          myauthProvider:
            token-uri: XXX
```

My expectation was that I hit "localhost:8080/test", I'll get response from end point x as a String. But instead, I get an html page -

[image]

Why do I've to login to access "/test" end point? My expectation was that "/test" will have no authentication. If I remove spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client dependency then the code works as expected.
How can I change this so that there is no authentication between client A and "/test" but communication between "/test" and end point x uses oauth 2.0?

Comment: Because the point of OAuth2 is that it delegates authentication. Like when you hit a website and it asks to access your google contacts - it pings you over to google, which asks whether you want that website to have access to your contacts. In this scenario x is google.

Comment: @BoristheSpider , in that case the authentication happens on some specific user action. How can I write the code in such a way then that "/test" doesnt use auth. Oauth should be used only when I hit end point x. 
Also, since I've already mentioned client id and secret in the yml, shouldn't it get the token using that info automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Spring Security does not automatically act as an oauth2 client and inject itself into your API calls. See the [oauth2 with webclient sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/webclient) for an example of how to do this. Note that you can replace `authorization-grant-type: code` with `authorization-grant-type: client_credentials` but the authorized client will still be scoped to the currently logged in user. Note that the user must be logged in by default, which in your example is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution that worked for me was removing spring security dependencies and making 2 rest API call.

1. In the first rest call, I hit custom oauth provider token url passing client id, secret. I get the access token in the response.
2. After that I hit end point x passing the token in the header
   manually.